# IRepository vs. IRepository<T>

Tags: .net, generics, repository

I'm trying to define one specific interface for all my repositories implement, than is just this:

```
public abstract class GeneralizedRepository
{
    readonly IDataModel _Model;

    public GeneralizedRepository(IDataModel Model) {
        if (Model == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        _Model = Model;
    }

    public IDataModel DataModel { get { return _Model; } }

    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
    public abstract T GetOne<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate);

    public abstract bool Contains<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    public abstract void Add<T>(T entity);
    public abstract void Update<T>(T entity);
    public abstract bool Remove<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

This is a class because my derived repositories have in common the instance DataModel

Now I have concrete implementations as:

```
public class DetailRep : GeneralizedRepository
{
    public DetailRep(IDataModel Model) : base(Model) { }
    public DetailRep(UnitOfWork Unit) : base(Unit.Model) { }

    public override IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override T GetOne<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool Contains<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Add<T>(T entity) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Update<T>(T entity) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool Remove<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But it is a **Detail Repository**, what i mean is that i want replace all **T**'s for the type **Detail**

But an error is thrown at compile time:

*Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type*

Comment: The types in the title of the question do not appear in the question at all!? Can you check your question again? And provide more details about the error. For example the line which produces the error? The calls to base(...) are wrong, but before explaining I would first need to understand what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your abstract class as a generic:

```
public abstract class GeneralizedRepository<T>
{
    readonly IDataModel _model;
    public GeneralizedRepository(IDataModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        _model = model;
    }
    public IDataModel DataModel { get { return _model; } }
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    public abstract T GetOne(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    public abstract bool Contains(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    public abstract void Add(T entity);
    public abstract void Update(T entity);
    public abstract bool Remove(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

And than on your derived class fill in the Type with your `Detail`:

```
public class DetailRep  : GeneralizedRepository<Detail>
{
    public DetailRep(IDataModel model)
        : base(model)
    {
    }
    public override IEnumerable<Detail> GetAll(){}
    public override Detail GetOne(Func<Detail, bool> predicate){}
    public override bool Contains(Func<Detail, bool> predicate){}
    public override void Add(Detail entity){}
    public override void Update(Detail entity){}
    public override bool Remove(Func<Detail, bool> predicate){}
}
```

Comment: but in that way if i have 10 repositories, and each one implement GeneralizedRepository<T>, where T is the type of the contents than repository contains the compiler will generate GeneralizedRepository<Type1>, GeneralizedRepository<Type2>, .... GeneralizedRepository<Type10>. I want only one abstract class and 10 derived classes.